# Javascript change image on mouse hover not working

Tags: javascript, html, hover

I have an html code as shown below. So far it is able to display the intended image. I also tried to change the src attribute and works completely fine.

```
<article id="memory-game">
    <a class="image"><img src="../../images/memory-game.png" id="memory-game" alt="" /></a>
    <h3 class="major">MEMORY GAME</h3>
    <p>Tkinter<br><br>A card-matching memory game implemented in Tkinter GUI;</p>
    <a href="#" class="special2" style="color: rgba(125, 125, 125, 1);">Confidential Source Code</a>
</article>
```

Now I have this script tag at the bottom of my  element. It is supposed to change the image of the above html code from png to gif upon mouse hover on the specified article id. Last time I used this code was about 3 months ago, and it doesn't seem to work now.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#memory-game").hover(
            function() {$(this).attr("src", "../../images/memory-game.gif");},
            function() {$(this).attr("src", "../../images/memory-game.png");}
        );
    });
</script>
```

I'm a javascript noob. Anybody could help me solve the png-to-gif-change-on-mouse-hover issue? Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: you set it to the gif and then immediately back to the png. why is that?

Comment: @MattEllen because it is supposed to return back to a png image on mouse leave from the element. I was using this same code 3 months ago and it was still working. Now, I tried to comment out the last function to avoid reverting back to png, but still the gif is not being displayed on mouse hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 elements using the same `id`. The `id` should be unique per document. jQuery is matching the first `id` so setting the `src` attribute on the `div` doesn't have any impact.

Remove the `id` from the article as follow

```html
<article>
    <a class="image"><img src="../../images/memory-game.png" id="memory-game" alt="" /></a>
    <h3 class="major">MEMORY GAME</h3>
    <p>Tkinter<br><br>A card-matching memory game implemented in Tkinter GUI;</p>
    <a href="#" class="special2" style="color: rgba(125, 125, 125, 1);">Confidential Source Code</a>
</article>
```